# changing projection of raster stack from HKH albers equal area conis to wgs84 in R

Tags: r

i want to change the projection of raster from KHK albers equal area conic projection to wgs84 in R. I use following code but could not succeed. Could anyone help me in this regard.
I use following code.

```
setwd('D:/amrit_work/amrit_R/snow_Algirothms')
raster_data <- list.files(path=getwd()) 
s <- stack(raster_data)
pr1 <- projectRaster(s, crs="+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)

setwd('D:/amrit_work/amrit_R/snow_Algirothms')
raster_data <- list.files(path=getwd()) 
s <- stack(raster_data)
crs(s) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"
```

See `?projection`. The `crs` (or `projection`) function in package `raster`:

> Get or set the coordinate reference system (CRS) of a Raster* object.

Comment: i tried crs(s) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84",
plot(s[[4]]) and still lon,lat doesn't appear in axis label